# How can I hide desktop icons but keep a custom wallpaper background?

Tags: nautilus, desktop-background, desktop-icons

**Background:**

Icons on the desktop can be managed as follows:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true # show icons
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false # hide icons
```

**Problem:**

If I set `show-desktop-icons` to `false`, my custom wallpaper background is no longer shown.

**Question:**

How can I hide desktop icons and keep my custom wallpaper background?

Comment: These icons are managed by a Nautilus daemon. If you `killall nautilus`, the desktop icons disappear. You can launch `nautilus --no-desktop` afterwards to restore the background daemon without showing desktop icons. Not sure if that affects the wallpaper though.

Comment: @ByteCommander can this be automatised or do I have to perform these commands manually each time?

Comment: You would have to find out what exactly is starting the Nautilus background daemon normally on login and then add the `--no-desktop` option to this call - if it works as intended. Have you tested if the effect of restarting the daemon with `--no-desktop` behaves as you want?

Comment: Yes, it does work!

Comment: Well, then you can either run something like `sleep 10 ; killall nautilus ; sleep 5 ; nautilus --no-desktop` as autostart command of your account, which would be the quick and dirty way, or you can search for how the Nautilus daemon normally gets started. That might be hard-coded somewhere deep in the Unity DE though, I have no idea.

Comment: Great idea! Now I need to modify the [Unity Files Launcher Icon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RAwAF.png) to also use the `no-desktop` parameter. Do you know which `.desktop` file I need to modify?

Comment: This would be of course `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried [this](https://gist.github.com/orschiro/b853483947cdecf9c831b1df9daaeee8/revisions) change without effect. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry but no, unfortunately. :-(

Comment: I found a solution! :-) Disable icons as described above and [use Feh to set the background](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Feh#As_a_desktop_wallpaper_manager).

Comment: Fine! Please post an answer describing how you did it. :)

Comment: It is done. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Disable Icons

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

## 2. Use [Feh](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Feh#As_a_desktop_wallpaper_manager)  to set the wallpaper

[image: Feh startup entry]

Comment: I understand that, but don't worry :-) http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer